# Is this an allowed step for working with infinite sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

I just started learning about infinite sequences, which are of course very interesting. Out of curiosity, I tried doing a proof that:

$${1,-1,1,-1 ...} = 0$$

This was pretty easy to do, if I could make a certain step. Now, this step makes a lot of intuitive sense to me, but I would like to know whether this is actually mathematically justifiable. Does it work in every scenario? The step is:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n =   \lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^{2n} + \lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^{2n+1} $$

Or more generally:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (a)^n =   \lim_{n \to\infty} (a)^{2n} + \lim_{n \to\infty} (a)^{2n+1} $$

The proof from there on isn't very difficult, so this is kind of the breaking point of my argument. Some insights on the matter would be very much appreciated!

Comment: No, sequences don't work like this...

Comment: Consider $a_n=1^n$; then it is patently false that $1=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n+1}=2$

Comment: I am impressed that the OP even thought to verify these ideas. That's a mark of good thinking in and of itself.

Comment: How can a sequence equal a number?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're trying to prove **is not true.**

If you have learned the formal definition of limit, it ought to be easily for you to prove directly from the definition that $0$ is *not* the limit of $(-1)^n$.

(Set $\varepsilon=\frac12$ and see that *no possible* $N$ can even begin to work).

---

In fact, your proposed rule

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =   \lim_{n \to\infty} a_{2n} + \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+1} $$
will yield clear falsehoods even for well-behaved sequences -- consider for example the sequence $1,1,1,1,\ldots$ whose limit is obviously $1$, so your rule would claim that $1=1+1$.

You may be confusing *sequences* for *series*: It *is* true that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1} $$
if both series on the right-hand side converge. (On the other hand, if neither of the right-hand series converge, it is still possible that the one on the left will).

Answer (score 7):

What you *can* say is that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n+1}$ both exist and are equal, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and equals those limits.

Moreover, in the traditional sense of limits, $(-1)^n$ does not converge at all, it has no limit.

Comment: @Stefan Sorry, can you elaborate? I do believe it's true for arbitrary sequences.